# Plot coefficients from multiple models with Coefplot manually

Tags: r, plot, regression, linear-regression, figure

I have some model output from a model object that is not supported by coefplot in R. I am trying to plot results from multiple models in one coefficient plot. I can do this with one model if I put in a vector with the coefficients and a vector with the standard errors. However, if I put a list of vectors to plot multiple models.

Reproducible example:

```
coefs_1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
coefs_2 <- c(4, 5, 6)

ses_1 <- c(0.5, 0.3, 0.6)
ses_2 <- c(0.7, 0.4, 0.5)
```

```
coefplot(coefs_1, sd = ses_1)
```

works, but

```
coefplot(list(coefs_1, coefs_2), sd = list(ses_1, ses_2))
```

throws an error. The error is:

```
Error in coefplot_prms(object = object, ..., sd = sd, ci_low = ci_low,  : 
  The first element of 'object' raises and error:
Error in nb * sd : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I tried using different ways of feeding coefficients and ses into the function but also get a variation of the same error. I feel like I am missing some essential piece of how this function works and processes input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify, the function `coefplot` you mention is from the library `fixest`.

The short answer:

```r
coefplot(list(
  matrix(c(coefs_1, ses_1, rep(NA, 6)), ncol = 4),
  matrix(c(coefs_2, ses_2, rep(NA, 6)), ncol = 4))
))
```

The long answer:

It looks like this function, besides a fitted model object, can also take a matrix as its input, which looks like the output of `coeftable(object)`. Here the object would be the fitted model (you can try this with `lm()`).

This output is a matrix where the first two rows are the estimate and std error and the next two rows anything else which is not used here (in the case of `lm()` it is the t-value and p-value).

Now, similar to a list of objects, the function can also take a list of these matrices, so you can use the code as shown above.

Comment: Thank you for your very useful and concise answer! That did help me a lot!